# Windows phone 8.1 Camera Initialisation - UnAuthorizedException

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to launch camera using MediaCapture api on my windows phone 8.1 universal app. The code works fine on Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 emulator. I am able to launch camera and take picture.

But it throws an UnauthorizedException on Windows Phone 8.1 device. Similar question is asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224102/windows-phone-8-1-camera-initialisation-access-denied-exception)

But, i dont know whether someone got around this problem. And I am sideloading application on device for testing. My requirement is to launch camera on sideloaded applications.

Code snippet:

Initializing MediaCapture:

```
                DeviceInformation cameraDevice = await GetCameraID();
                if (cameraDevice != null)
                {
                    mMediaManager_ = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
                    var settings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
                    settings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
                    settings.MediaCategory = Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCategory.Other;
                    settings.AudioProcessing = Windows.Media.AudioProcessing.Default;
                    settings.VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id;                       

                    await mMediaManager_.InitializeAsync(settings);
                    mMediaManager_.RecordLimitationExceeded += new Windows.Media.Capture.RecordLimitationExceededEventHandler(RecordLimitationExceeded);
                    mMediaManager_.Failed += new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureFailedEventHandler(RecordFailed);

                }
```

Taking Photo:

```
                mMediaStorageFile_ = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
                await mMediaManager_.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, mMediaStorageFile_);                   
                mCameraScreen_.setPreviewImage(mMediaStorageFile_);
```

Comment: It might be hard to find a workaround for *UnauthorizedException*. IMO it's a bug which appeard after last update - my working example also throws exception (so MSDN example). We will probably have to wait till the next update.

Comment: Since we are running Windows Phone 8.1 OS preview on device. It may need proper firmware update or so to support latest MediaCapture api. So, i am just thinking code might work fine on official release of OS. Again, this is just my hunch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this bug has been corrected with the last update.

As I've tested on developer preview version 8.10.14176.243, `MediaCapture.InitializeAsync` should work now without problems.