# Capturing Video in WP 8.1 Preview Back with Universal Apps

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've a problem initializing video capturing in my mobile. I want to capture the video stream to preview in mobile and get captures to read codes like QR, BarCodes...

I've mark the capabilities Webcam, Microphone and VideosLibrary (I think it's not needed but I marked to test).

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
        <CaptureElement Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myCaptureElement"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.css

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }
    public async Task StartCapture()
    {
        try
        {
            var _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

            myCaptureElement.Source = _mediaCapture;
            await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //StartCapture().Wait();
    }
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await StartCapture();
    }
}
```

I've tested in the click event and in the OnNavigatedTo and it fails in the same way.

If I test in **mobile device** I've the following error when press F10 on **InitializeAsync call**:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at App2.MainPage.<StartCapture>d__0.MoveNext()}
```

I've read a lot of articles with solucions like gant more Permisions, set devideId, configure settings, ... and all of this fails again.

In some places inform this is a problema with the versión Back of WP8.1 Preview and suggest to install Cyan version and others said it's not needed

¿How can I capture images? ¿there are more people with the same problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: More people have the same problem - it seems that it appeard after one of the updates: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25224102/2681948), [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25291122/2681948) the issue [posted as bug](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/6294849-mediacapture-initializeasync-throws-unauthorized) at user voice.

Comment: +1 it's a bug, even an official MS example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/AdvancedCamera-ba47da27 does not work. It's hurting us hard in production.

Comment: It's true Romasz, I update to cyan and it works fine... Thank you very much